# Swift/Decryption in search bar

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, uisearchbar

EDIT!!!

I got this search bar which with some data needs to decrypt it before searching. Im pretty sure I figured out where to decrypt it. But since im new, I cant really get it to work.

This is my function for filtered users. The data called "Personnr" needs to be decrypted before search.
I start by getting the String "ePersonnr" and the encryption key from the database. But when I run it, it just keeps adding a lot of profiles in the search bar?

```
func filterUsers (searchText:String) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
        var fNavn = false
        var personNr = false
        var searchBil = false
        var telefonNr = false
        var korekortNr = false
        //This below is for the decryption
        databaseRef.child("Buyers").queryOrdered(byChild: "ePersonnr").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let key = snapshot.key
            let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "ePersonnr")
            self.usersArray.append(snapshot)

            self.ref = Database.database().reference()

            self.ref.child("Encryption").child("key").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let uid = self.otherUser?["key"] as? String
                self.otherUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                self.otherUser?.setValue(uid, forKey: "key")
                self.key1 = self.otherUser?["key1"] as? String

                let input = key
                let iv = self.key1
        //Above is for the decryption


        if let Navn = user!["Navn"] as? String {
            fNavn =  Navn.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if let Bil = user!["Bil"] as? String {
            searchBil = Bil.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }

        //Decryption of data
        if let Personnr = user!["ePersonnr"] as? String {
            let des = try! input.aesDecrypt(key: self.key1!, iv: iv!)
            self.Personnr = des
            personNr = Personnr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if let Kørekortnr = user!["Kørekortnr"] as? String {
            korekortNr = Kørekortnr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if let Telefonnr = user!["Telefonnr"] as? String {
            telefonNr = Telefonnr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }

            }) { (error) in
                print(error)
            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }

        return fNavn || personNr || searchBil || korekortNr || telefonNr



    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

EDIT!!!

I checked in another project and the decryption works as it should. So its not the commands. It must be where to place the code. I guess.
This is how it looks like if I try to search:
https://ibb.co/cngfkb

Any ideas?

Comment: Any information needed or doesn´t anyone know how to?